# Can I use less memory to save one-digit number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I know Python isn't the best memory - managment language, but is there a way to store small numbers into smaller memory part than integer?

I am currently working on Python program with breadth-first search and I use one parameter in class which can only have value of 0 to 9. I want to store this as effectively as possible, because - well if I have size of 1B or 3B matters when you have to go through several thousands variabiles in running-memory.

Comment: At several thousand objects you'd then still be in the KB range. Unless you are running on some very resource constrained platform this won't make much difference

Comment: Is this an embedded system?  Most of the time a regular integer is small enough not to worry about.

Comment: In CPython, small integers are cached. So, there is only the overhead of the pointer, 8 bytes. If you wanted to store many small integers, though, you could use `array.array` or even `numpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure that is really worth it, but you can always encode integers in `[0, 1, ..., 9]` with 4 bits and store several of them in a python `int`. packing and unpacking them is then some bit-shifting and masking:

```
SHIFT = 4
MASK = 0xf

integers = [0, 1, 5, 3]

# pack list into int
store = 0
for i in integers:
    store <<= SHIFT
    store ^= i

# unpack list from int
unpacked = []
for _ in range(len(integers)):
    unpacked.append(store & MASK)
    store >>= SHIFT
unpacked.reverse()

assert integers == unpacked
```

the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module might also be useful.

Answer (score -1):

With native python code you can't as python's `int` is hardcoded to take 24-bytes to support the long integer number. Which is efficient as in your case the function parameter accepts single digit number

But if you remember C has a solution, `unsigned char` in C takes 1-byte and has number range from `0 - 255`

So in python it will look like this

```py
>>> from ctypes import c_ubyte
>>> ten = c_ubyte(10)
>>> ten
c_ubyte(10)
>>> type(ten)
<class 'ctypes.c_ubyte'>
>>> ten.value
10
>>> type(ten.value)
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

Comment: Do the `ctypes` wrappers not have any memory overhead?

Comment: On my system, that `ctypes.c_ubyte` value has *far* more overhead than a plain `int`.  This would only be useful for memory savings if you used a rather large array of ubytes, such that there is only one instance of overhead for all of the values.